# How long can ubuntu work on a usb drive?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb-drive, external-hdd

I have a 128gb usb drive lying around and I was planning on installing ubuntu on it. But then I started having concerns about how long the usb would last. I read that an average usb flash drive can have up to 1 million read/write operations before becoming corrupted. So, how long would it take to reach this number? Anyone having experiences with the lifespan of usb drives with ubuntu on them?

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to answer this, it will vary so incredibly much.  I will say, I have several systems in kiosk modes that utilize tempfs as much as possible.  Because my user isn't saving real data the entire system runs in tempfs which is created on boot from the flash drive but you could extend the life by moving as much as you can off the flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the USB drive. Cheap USBs such as consumer Lexar drives may die fairly quickly, and are fairly slow.

However, there are some, such as the Sandisk Cruzer Extreme that are basically SSDs, and have much higher tolerances than cheaper drives.

I recommend that when permanently installing Ubuntu on a USB drive that you use a light distribution such as Lubuntu and disable journaling. This will significantly reduce write cycles to the drive- however, **disabling journalling puts you at a far higher risk of disk corruption. Make sure to make backups!**

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a 32gb usb 3.0 flash drive from sandisk. what i would notice is that it would get very hot very quickly. so what i did is. I ripped of the plastic casing and removed the metal casing. then i soldered 15 gauge wires on the metal casing and put some thermal compound sandwiched between the nand flash and the metal casing. Then put it back together without the plastic. I've been running this now for about 2 and a half months now and still works great. I use this daily and this is my primary computer for coding, watching on youtube, playing alien shooter and some other games etc.. In the past I've tried running ubuntu 16.04 without this modification and extended exposure to heat did kill my drive. In my experience heat is your number 1 enemy when running ubuntu in a Flash drive. oh and dont use usb 2.0. not a great experience

Answer (score -1):

If you are worried about the lifetime of the flash drive you should probably use a copy to ram distro like Puppy Linux on it, instead of a regular distribution.

A frugal installation of Puppy Linux resides in RAM and writes changes to the Flash drive only on shutdown and/or on configured time intervals/on user request. This reduces the number of file ops.

So if you are really worried about the lifetime of your Flash drive you could look into something like that.

Links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions_that_run_from_RAM
http://puppylinux.org/wikka/FrugalOrFullInstallation

Comment: This is about putting *Ubuntu* on a flash drive on *AskUbuntu*, and the flash drive's corresponding lifetime, not "what distro is best to run on a flash drive?"

Comment: If the shop next door has what the customer wants it's just good custom to let them know.

Comment: Then you could explain *why* it isn't a good idea to install Ubuntu on a flash drive, and answer the question "what is the lifetime *under Ubuntu*". Then, you can point out additional distributions.

Comment: Apologies. I expanded my answer.